# Field label not displaying

Tags: 8, theming

I have a custom template to display content (Resources) in a certain display mode (Feature Card) which is a web component. When I have labels set to display on the fields, no labels show up. I have tried using `kint(field[i])` to look for the label because I thought that maybe I was missing a variable, but I couldn't find anything. Is there something else I need to add to my twig to get labels to appear?

```
<feature-card {{ my_attributes.addClass(my_classes).setAttribute('id', 'feature-card') }}>
{% for field in content.title %}
    {% for i in 0..1 if field[i] is defined %}
        <div slot="title">{{ field[i] }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for field in content.feature_top %}
    {% for i in 0..field|length if field[i] is defined %}
        <div slot="feature-top">{{ field[i] }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for field in content.feature_left %}
    {% for i in 0..field|length  if field[i] is defined %}
        <div slot="feature-left">{{ field[i] }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for field in content.feature_right %}
    {% for i in 0..field|length  if field[i] is defined %}
        <div slot="feature-right">{{ field[i] }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for field in content.feature_center %}
    {% for i in 0..field|length  if field[i] is defined %}
        <div slot="feature-center">{{ field[i] }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

</feature-card>
```

Comment: The label is displayed by the field template, which you bypass if you render only the field items and ignore the rest of `{{ content.field_example }}`.

Comment: Okay so how do I not bypass the field template?

Comment: Print `{{ content.field_example }}` and theme the field items `field.html.twig`.